# Google Map Android v2 - Polylines intersection

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, intersection, polyline

In an application I'm currently developing, I allow the user to draw his own way on a Google Map Android v2.

For that, I capture the `onTouch` / `action_move` event and I convert the `x` and `y` of the event to a Google Map `LatLng`. Then, with these `LatLng` I build a `PolylineOptions` that I finally add on the map.

Now, I would like to know if there is an intersection in this polyline and if it is the case, I would like to obtain the coordinate of this point.

Is there a way to do that ? Maybe by converting `Polyline` into `Path` and `Region` ?

I have try the latest proposition without success.

Thank you in advance for you help :)

Comment: is there a built in method? no you have to do the math yourself

Comment: Perhaps this can help you http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html. Using latitude as 'x' and longitude as 'y', looping through the LatLng's in an AsyncTask for instance.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535476/how-to-find-intersect-between-two-polylines-in-android/49550178#49550178