# Check if polygon inside google map "valid"

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

How to check that a polygon inside google map is "valid", I mean as follows:

**Valid:**

[image: Valid]

**Not valid:**

[image]

```
PolygonOptions po = new PolygonOptions()
                            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                            .fillColor(Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(3);

                    for(int i=0;i<listLatLng.size();i++){
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(listLatLng.get(i)));
                        po.add(listLatLng.get(i));
                    }

                    googleMap.addPolygon(po);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Conceptually, both are valid. I think you are talking about Regular and irregular (Convex and non-Convex )shapes of polygons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471962/how-do-i-efficiently-determine-if-a-polygon-is-convex-non-convex-or-complex check this.

Comment: looking at shis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon, I don't think it's about "convex/non convex", since in that link, the shape of the sample image will still able to produce the "blue" area despite being non convex. 

So, what I want to know is how to differ it with the "not valid" or the shape that cannot produce the blue area above, in android.

Comment: @ZaidMirza 's link correctly suggests the 'Not Valid' case as representative of a complex polygon.  The test for such a case is to test each polyline segment for intersection with all other member polylines.  Here's a discussion of the cross-product test for intersection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect/565282#565282 ; and an apparent android-java implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535476/how-to-find-intersect-between-two-polylines-in-android